# find partial match between two data frame

Tags: sql, r, rsqlite

I have two data frames.

```
head(NEexp)
 Gene   Transcript Ratio_log2      FDR
HLHmgamma HLHmgamma-RA   3.759200 1.09e-10
Brd       Brd-RA   3.527000 2.66e-08
CG4080     CG4080-RE   3.378500 2.95e-50
RpII215   RpII215-RA   3.343967 1.82e-10

head(excel$gene)
Enhancer of split mgamma, helix-loop-helix
distal antenna
CG4080 gene product from transcript CG4080-RB
```

As you can see, the two gene column match partially(HLHmgamma matches Enhancer of split mgamma, helix-loop-helix; CG4080 matches CG4080 gene product from transcript CG4080-RB), is there anyway that I can link these two?
codes I have tried so far:

```
genename=as.character(NEexp$Gene)
query=paste("select * from excel where excel.gene LIKE \"", genename,"\ ",sep"")
Newtable<-dbGetQuery(con,query)

dbGetQuery(con,"select * from excel, NEexp where excel.gene LIKE % "NEexp$Gene" %")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `merge` , which basically is the same as `join` in SQL. But first you might want to split `excel$gene` to get the part you want to match.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html